# Left side central locking not fully opening

Tags: vauxhall, central-locking

This relates to my old Vauxhall Meriva 2004. The central locking stopped working so I replaced the micro fuse into slot 19 and hey-presto it started to work again.  Well…  the right hand side does.  The left-hand side only partially lifts the lock on the FNS, but the RNS doesn't lift at all.  Is my motor on the way out or is there another culprit?

I don't want to spend a lot of money getting this repaired if I can do it myself as the car is only worth £500 and I'll be selling it soon.

Comment: If you are selling it soon, then why bother.  It won't make the car more valuable and you stand the chance of making more damage.

Comment: Just wondered if there was anything that could be hindering it working.  I'll leave it be if best left alone.